# Trouble drawing with MouseDragged in Java

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

there's a problem drawing or Setting size of a JPanel when i drag the mouse,
the location i setted where i click and the size depending of the drag position(X and Y) drawing a resizable rectangle(JPanel).

```
private void panelMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    rSX = (int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
    rSY = (int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
    rectanguloDefault.setBounds(rX,rY,rSX-rX,rSY-rY);
}                                  

private void panelMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    rX = (int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
    rY = (int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
    rectanguloDefault.setLocation(rX,rY);
}
```

but when i drag mouse in a negative coordinate of the click(Start of drawing) it disappear.

here a better explain
http://i.picasion.com/resize80/49c88c55d4c11c53c020acfcc4fc2f45.png

Comment: Why are you using `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo()` when `MouseEvent` gives you the mouse position within the coordinate space of the component which generated the event!? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Oh ok i will, i forget that can get position with mouseEvent :p

Answer (score 2):

> but when i drag mouse in a negative coordinate

```
 rectanguloDefault.setBounds(rX,rY,rSX-rX,rSY-rY);
```

Your width/height calculation always assumes you drag the mouse in a positive direction.

You need to use the absolute value of the two points:

```
int width = Math.abs(rSX - rX);
int height = Math.abs(rSY - rY);
rectanguloDefault.setBounds(rX, rY, width, height);
```

Your x/y values will also need to be the minimum of (rX and rSX) and (ry and rSY). You can use the Math.min(...) method for this.

Comment: this has happended http://i.picasion.com/resize80/49c88c55d4c11c53c020acfcc4fc2f45.png